# how to extract the exact data from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i got this array from an database...how to get the exact value attribute......

```
Array
(
    [0] => TRowResult Object
        (
            [row] => tests
            [columns] => Array
                (
                    [a21ha:link_0] => TCell Object
                        (
                            [value] =>testsample
                            [timestamp] => 1265010584060
                        )

                    [a21ha:link_1] => TCell Object
                        (
                            [value] => example
                            [timestamp] => 1265092697040
                        )

                )

        )
```

how to get the [value] alone in php

Answer (score 3):

```
print $myArray[0]->columns['a21ha:link_0']->value;
```

This would give you the first. To get all, you'd have to loop through the contents.

```
foreach ($myArray[0]->columns as $column) {
  print $column->value;
}
```

Comment: Isn’t it `$array[0]->columns['a21ha:link_0']->value`?

Comment: @Gumbo: I'm not able to test right now, so I'll just take your word for it. I was certain that with `columns` being an array, I could access its first item via index.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed your array called $array:

```
foreach($array as $arridx => $rowobj){
    foreach($rowobj->columns as $cellid => $rowcell){
        echo $rowcell->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to do `as $arridx => $rowobj`, `as $rowobj` is sufficient, but nevertheless correct.

Comment: yeah, it's just maybe he/she want to know the key index.