# PHP Array generated from Xpath Query - Trying to extract data

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xpath, simplexml

I am currently attempting to extract values from an array that was generated by an SIMPLEXML/XPATH Query. I have had no success with my attempts if anyone can take look would be greatly appreciated.

I am looking just to extract ReclaimDate. I have tried a few functions and some of the advice on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182465/how-to-extract-the-exact-data-from-an-array-in-php) with no luck.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [ReclaimDate] => 05/15/2008
                        [ReclaimPrice] => 555555555
                        [_Owner] => ownername
                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `(string)$myvar[0][0]['ReclaimDate']` -- if you could provide a short example doc and sample code, it'd be easier to provide a solution that's guaranteed to work.  BTW the SO post you linked appears to not be about SimpleXML, so it's probably not helpful.

Comment: can you post the response data (or URL to it) and/or the PHP you're using to get this data as a SimpleXMLElement?

Answer (score 1):

If I just had to take a stab, I'd agree that what @Frank Farmer said should work:

```
    // if $myVar is what you print_r'ed
    echo (string)$myVar[0][0]['ReclaimDate'];
```

or this

```
    echo (string)$myVar[0][0]->attributes('ReclaimDate');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-4587

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved thanks to Frank Farmer and Dan Beam.

This worked : `echo (string)$check_reo[0][0]['ReclaimDate']`

For anyone that is looking to use SimpleXML and XPATH to extract and write some basic logic from an XML file this is what worked for me.

`$xmlstring = <<<XML <?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?> <YOURXMLGOESHERE>TEST</YOURXMLGOESHERE> XML;`

`$xpathcount = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring); // Load XML for XPATH Node Counts`

`$doc = new DOMDocument(); // Create new DOM Instance for Parsing`

`$xpathcountstr = $xpathcount->asXML(); // Xpath Query`

`$doc->loadXML($xpathcountstr); // Load Query Results`

`$xpathquery = array($xpathcount->xpath("//XMLNODEA[1]/XMLNODEB/*[name()='KEYWORDTOCHECKIFXMLCEXISTS']"));`

`print_r ($xpathquery) // CHECK Array that is returned from the XPATH query`

`Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [ReclaimDate] => 05/15/2008
                        [ReclaimPrice] => 555555555
                        [_Owner] => ownername
                    )

```
        )

) // Array RETURNED`
```

`echo (string)$xpathquery[0][0]['ReclaimDate'] // EXTRACT THE VALUE FROM THE ARRAY COLUMN;`

This site helped me receive a better understanding on how XPATH can search XML very easily with a lot more features than what I had previously known.

http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/examples.html

Here is the simple XML Function that worked for me

`$xmlread = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, "simple_xml_extended");`

`class simple_xml_extended extends SimpleXMLElement { // Read XML and get attribute
     public    function    Attribute($name){
        foreach($this->Attributes() as $key=>$val) {
            if($key == $name)
                return (string)$val;

```
    }
}
```

}`

Here is the Function action when extracting Single Values with an attribute based XML results

`$GETVAR1 = $xmlread->XMLNODE1->XMLNODE2->XMLNODE3->XMLNODE4->XMLNODE5[0]->Attribute('XMLNODE5ATTRIBUTE');`

This might not be the most efficient or best method, but its what ended working our for me. Hope this helps someone out who is still unclear about SIMPLEXML and XPATH.

An additional link for further insight: http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/handling-xml-data